# Sitecore User Roles and cloning

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, user-roles

When cloning an item in Sitecore 6.4 the clone inherits the security settings of the cloned (parent) item. Can I create a security role that applies to the clone but not to the parent? Or does that security role require the same access rights to the parent as to the clone?

I'd like to be able to create a security role whereby the role can only read the parent, but can read/write on the clone. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, which was originally asked because I'd overlooked some language settings.

Yes, it is possible to set up security roles as described above, just as any other site section. Be aware that any explicit security settings will be cloned, so you may wish to strip security settings from cloned items first.